# Postgres GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (sequence_options)

Tags: postgresql, sequence

The Postgres documentation [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createtable.html) says for **GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (sequence_options)** that:

> The optional sequence_options clause can be used to override the options of the sequence. See CREATE SEQUENCE for details.

The documentation [CREATE SEQUENCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createsequence.html) no longer calls them as options but parameters. Anyway, the name is also listed as a parameter. The examples are rather taciturn. Is it possible to override the name of the sequence that will be created for an identity column?

Answer (score 2):

No, the name is not an option because it is not optional (as the documentation says).

Comment: Is that "No" for an answer or as an explanation why the name is called a parameter instead of an option? Everything is overridable there, I don't see the reason why the name should not be. There's nothing in the doc stating the name should be an exception. I just couldn't find an example. But that doesn't mean much, I haven't found examples for some other ones either. Doc says "See CREATE SEQUENCE for details." but there are no details how the info found at CREATE SEQUENCE should be used in CREATE TABLE.

Comment: Well, you asked "Is it possible to override the name of the sequence that will be created for an identity column?", and the answer is "no". The rest of the answer explains that the name is not an option, but `INCREMENT`, `START`, `CACHE` and others are. (for example: "The **optional** clause `CACHE cache` specifies...")

Answer (score 2):

It turned out the answer is yes, there is a way. The twist is that while it is obvious you're giving sequence options between the parenthesis, simply saying **NAME** xyz is not enough, you still have to tell postgres that the name you provide is **SEQUENCE NAME**:

```
CREATE TABLE test(
    i int PRIMARY KEY GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY(SEQUENCE NAME xyz START WITH 1)
) ;
```